# Checking and changing TextView text color

Tags: java, android

I have ScroolView and it's inside Linear layout. In this linear layout i added programmically around 20 TextView. When i press any of those TextView i change it color to RED (at first it was white). When i press again the same TextView i check his color and if it's is RED i again make it white.

What i want to do:

I press for example 1 TextView and make it RED. Then when i press 2 TextView i make this one RED and i want to make 1 TextView WHITE. This functionality should be at all TextView.

So any idea's how to do this ?

Comment: take an array of textview..check the index on which you are clicking and make it red and make other than that textview white..

Comment: set onClick() to your all textview and in onClick() iterate all textview with loop for checking color make clicked one at RED and others WhIte. Also make condition for if clicked one has RED make it White.

Comment: cant u set boolean values to check whenever the color is red(Boolean red=true) or white(red=false),based on the boolean values,check it and set the colors of the remaining text to white or red on evry text click.

Comment: In this case you can use two drawable, and you can put your if condition into onclick method. if(textView.getBackground() == drawable)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean to say at a time you need only one textview to be red. You can do this using 2 variables. One is a boolean `colored`. This indicates that at least one TextView is colored. Another is a TextView variable. Create a TextView variable `lastColoredTextView`. Let it be null initially. Then whenever the textview is clicked, assign the `lastColoredTextView` to the clicked TextView. Then whenever you are clicking, just check if `colored` then change the color of `lastColoredTextView` to white.

Answer (score 0):

Change class name and it will work fine.

public class Test_stflowActivity extends Activity {

```
TextView current_red_txt_box = null;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    TextView tv = null;
    LinearLayout lp = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());
    lp.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    View.OnClickListener txt_click = new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            current_red_txt_box.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            TextView tv = (TextView) v;
            tv.setTextColor(Color.RED);
            current_red_txt_box = tv;
        }
    };
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        tv = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
        tv.setId(i);
        tv.setTextSize(40);
        tv.setText("you text");
        tv.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        tv.setOnClickListener(txt_click);
        lp.addView(tv);
        current_red_txt_box = tv;
    }
    setContentView(lp);
}
```

}